# ActionCable.server.broadcast won't broadcast

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, pusher, actioncable

I am trying to migrate a rails application from using Pusher to ActionCable.
In the server side code this is the ActionCable Channel:

```
class PagesChannel < ApplicationCable::Channel
     def subscribed
        stream_from 'pages'
     end
     def speak(data)
        ActionCable.server.broadcast('pages',data)
     end
 end
```

and on the client side this is the subscriber code:

```
const app=ActionCable.createConsumer("wss://localhost.branch.co:3000/cable");
const channel =app.subscriptions.create("PagesChannel",{
    connected:()=>{
        console.log("connected")
    },
    received:()=>{
        console.log("got mail")
    }
})
```

In the official website https://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_cable_overview.html It's mentioned that:

> Then, elsewhere in your Rails application, you can broadcast to such a room by calling broadcast:

I interpreted that to mean that in my rails app, I can call
 `ActionCable.server.broadcast('pages',data)`
and It will be broadcasted to all subscribers.
Can you call this only inside a Channel class? and if so how do you call a method of a channel class from server side.
I am able to verify that my channel subscriptions from client are connected. I can even call

`channel.perform("speak");`

in my JS code from my client and have it broadcast to all clients.

I am running a server above code , all configs, routes.rb paths are all set. After running the server,
I am using rails console via
`bundle exec rails console`
and typing
`ActionCable.server.broadcast("pages",{})`
there is no received message on client side, no errors are shown in console.
my client is running above code.
I have made sure it isn't a cross domain error.

Answer (score 1):

It is hard to help without seeing the whole app, but you should be able to call `ActionCable.server.broadcast('pages',data)` from anywhere.
My guess is, you don't have redis configured correctly, you should verify that.